# Matlab syntax explanation for range

Tags: matlab, indexing, syntax

I am trying to convert the matlab syntax below tp py
`MainDiag(2*n*(3:m-3) - 1) = 6*alfa1+alfa2` where alpha1 and alpha2 is constant. m=961, n=220 and MainDiag is a very large matrix of dimension 1 by 422840.

My question is : is  **(3:m-3)** similar to for loop in matlab? However, how is it looping with out a for loop? Can anyone elaborately explain me the syntax. I want to convert this line to Python. I am also concerned about the indexing when converted to python.

Answer (score 0):

No. The closest equivalent to `(3:m-3)` (all numbers from 3 up to including (m-3)) would be using numpy

```py
np.arange(3, m-2)  # -2 as this is not inclusive
```

this allocates memory up front and constructs an array with all these numbers in a vector, just like matlab's `a:b` syntax does.

However, it's rarely necessary to allocate this memory up front, instead of just abstractly representing the range is faster and shorter.

```py
range(3, m-2)  # -2 as this is not inclusive
```

Often this is used as an index operation on a numpy array (or a normal list), in which case we can use the : operator

```py
MainDiag[(2*n*3):((2*n*3)*(m-2)) - 2] = ...
```

(I hope i got all the offsets correctly here; normally when porting over to a 0-based index language, quite a lot of changes are made to indexing like this, such as starting off the values of `m` as zero instead of 1 etc.)